# Adding ImageView Inside Base Adapter Programatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a GridView adapter(For gallery used).
What i want is to put Image(Check Image) when the photo is clicked.
But I am unable to do that with this code.

```
  @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        cbClicked = false;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelayout, parent, false);

        final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        final LinearLayout imgTop = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTop);

        ImageView img2 = new ImageView(ActivityReviewUpload.this);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_my_loc);
        imgTop.addView(text);
   return view;
 }
```

And for my XML is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imgTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:padding="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is an example of what I'm doing.
In this example it's number,
what I'm doing is i will put just CHECK in the selected images.
[image]

The image is not showing.
what am i doing wrong in this part?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's some problem with your `BaseAdapter`:

1. You should use `ViewHolder` or `ReyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` to avoid laggy when scrolling your `ListView`.
2. Look at this block of code:

   ```
   ImageView img2 = new ImageView(ActivityReviewUpload.this);
   img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_my_loc);
   imgTop.addView(text);
   ```

   Above code will be called everytime you sroll your `ListView`. Therefore, you always add new `ImageView` to each row when scrolling. You should remove it.
3. How to achieve what you want? Do it as below:

   ```
   // declare selectedPosition = -1 in your `Adapter`
   // in your get view added below code:
   img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           selectedPosition = position;
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   });
   cb.setChecked(selectedPosition == position? true: false);
   ```

   Those code will change checkbox state every time you click to your image.